# slowing down frame rate on Julia Animation object?

Tags: julia

let's say i have the following list :

```
pop = [5,4,3,4,2,5,1,6,7,6,10,13,5,8,8]
```

I then put them into a DataFrame, and for each row, append the value of the first column to a list. I then plot and frame the list to produce the animation :

```
df = DataFrame(pop, :auto)
a = Animation()
li = []
for i in df.x1
    append!(li,i)
    plt = plot(li, ylim=(0,20), xlim=(0,length(df.x1)))
    frame(a, plt)
end
gif(a)
```

[image]

The frame rate for Animation object is too fast, i would like to slow it down, how do i do that?

Comment: What package is the `gif` function used in the last line from? It doesn't seem to  be part of either `Animations.jl` or `Javis.jl` afaict.

Answer (score 0):

the easy answer is gif(a, fps = *whatever i want the frame rate to be*)